# Checking If Intervals Are of Equal Length in a List

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<foo>` that has two properties:
`start_time` and `end_time`

Assume that we have 100 records in that list. How can I check if all intervals are of equal length? In other terms, I'd like to know if the values of the difference between end and start times for all `foo` objects are equal.

Where (`value = end_time-start_time`).

Is it possible to achieve this in a single `LINQ` line?

Thanks, appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can write something like this:

```
var list = new List<foo>();
var areAllEqual = list.GroupBy(l => (l.end_time - l.start_time)).Count() == 1;
```

Alternatively, if you want to do more with that information:

```
var differences = list.GroupBy(l => (l.end_time - l.start_time)).ToList();
var numDifferences = differences.Count();
var areAllEqual = numDifferences == 1;
var firstDifference = differences.First().Key;
var allDifferences = differences.Select(g => g.Key);
```

Comment: `.All()` returns a `Boolean`?

Comment: @user1027620 Yes, it returns `true` if the predicate is true for all values. Though, it was redundant, so I've updated the code to be more succinct

Comment: Is it possible to know what this interval is?

Comment: @user1027620 Yes, to get every interval you'd write: `list.GroupBy(l => (l.end_time - l.start_time)).Select(g => g.Key)`. To get the first (and unassumingly only, once you've made the right checks), you simply add `First()` to the end.

Comment: So `list.GroupBy(l => (l.end_time - l.start_time)).Select(g => g.Key).First()` ? Given that the values should be equal... Correct?

Comment: @user1027620 Yep, that's right. Take a look at my edit, it will give you a few examples of how to use the data

Comment: @user1027620 No worries, mate :)

Comment: Consider ToLookup instead of GroupBy().ToList()

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
var first = items.First;
var duration = first.end_time - first.start_time;

var allEqual = items.All(i => duration == (i.end_time - i.start_time))
```